# Invoke objects' method at a specific time C#

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am a bit confused and looking for advice.

The idea of what I want to do:

```
Program started 
foreach file in directory 'tasks'
   Deserialize file to object
   DateTime date = GetExcecutionDate()
   if (Date.Now.DateDiff(date) < 0)
        async object.Excecute()
   else
        //Set task for file to execute at date
End foreach
Programs continue executing


When Task is called, I need to know filename
async
    Deserialize file to object
    object.Execute();
    ReloadTask(filename); //Sets new fire time for this file
```

What is the best way to implement this mechanism. All I need is how to force program to call specific method which will receive string at a specific time.In which way I should dig - Timers or Taskers or something else?

Comment: Just create a Class that holds the `date` and `filename`, then create a `List<ClassName>` to hold those instances.  Now use a standard Timer control and set its Interval to however often you want to check if the date/times have been passed (once every minute?).  In the Tick event of the Timer, iterate over the list and see if any of the items should be processed...

Answer (score 0):

You could get the next time it will run and subtract now() and set a timer to run your actions:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = date.Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(1));
double interval = timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
Timer _timer = new Timer();
_timer.Interval = interval;
_timer.Elapsed += PerformAction ;
_timer.AutoReset = false;
_timer.Start();
```

with PerformAction somewhere:

```
public void PerformAction (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
```